# r.recode error with QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis, convert

Yesterday, I successfully ran the r.recode Grass-command from QGIS 3.2 Bonn on a Windows 10 machine to recalculate a DEM-geotiff. Today, I installed QGIS 3.4 Madeira and de-installed all older QGIS-installations, including 3.2 (by deleting manually the respective folders).
When I retried the same r.recode function with the new QGIS in the same project with the same geo-tiff, I got an error. The same if I start a completely new project and try other DEM-geotiffs.

I don't really understand the error message: does it have something to do that QGIS is not able to start grass GIS? Any idea how to solve the problem?

Here is the eror message:

```
Starting GRASS GIS...

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Algorithm.py", line 411, in processAlgorithm
Grass7Utils.executeGrass(self.commands, feedback, self.outputCommands)
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Utils.py", line 372, in executeGrass
for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, ''):
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 81: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Similar UTF-8 errors were reported here with QGIS 3.4 as well, seems to be a generic problem?